# Salesforce marketing cloud date and time

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, sqlserver

In salesforce marketing cloud UI (Tracking) , I see a delivered date as 8/12/2021 9.04.

In the sql on Jobs data view , i get delivered date 12/8/2021 2:04:00 AM

I know ,

1. both dates are same and correct.
2. UI date is based on User setting showing in CET  in format d/mm/yyyy, while the sql is giving system date in utc

How can i convert dates in sql, so that it looks like UI

I tried

1. AT Time zone --> This correct the time part and then i get the same time as UI.

Problem is

1. How do i format the date plus use the AT timezone together.

This is failing, any thoughts on the same

Comment: Half part of my question is answered by above link. i had referred it and was able to convert to correct time zone . The problem i have i have 2 part operation in single statement and dont know how to convert it (1) onvert date from mm//dd//yyyy format to dd/yy/yyyy   (2) and convert time zone . The above url answers (2) from above. The answer i am seeking is both part 1 and part 2 into a single statement

Comment: Just to provide final Update. as managed to solved the problem. My solution is very specific to my scenario and it wouldn't work for all. (1) I used the To TimeZone approch so that the time part changes from Salesforce timezone to my time zone .

Comment: Select
T1.JobID as JobId,
CONVERT(datetime,(T1.DeliveredTime AT TIME ZONE 'Central Standard Time' AT TIME ZONE 'Central European Standard Time'),0) as SentTime,
T1.EmailName as EmailName,
T1.EmailSubject as Subject,
T1.FromName as FromName,
T1.FromEmail as FromEmailAddress,
T1.TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID as TriggeredSendDefinition,
T1.EmailID as EmailID,
T1.AccountID as AccountID,
T1.DynamicEmailSubject as DynamicEmailSubject,
T1.EventID as EventID
From
    _Job T1 WITH (NOLOCK)

Comment: for part (2) , i  used javascript to format the date on display . {
                    data: 'SentTime',
                    render: function(data, type, row) {
                        var dateSplit = data.split('/');
                        return type === "display" || type === "filter" ?
                            dateSplit[1] + '/' + dateSplit[0] + '/' + dateSplit[2] :
                            data;
                    }
                }...as seen i am swaping month and days to get required format